# wordpress theme install Strict standards

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I install new theme and now I get:

```
Strict standards: Declaration of DropDown_Nav_Menu::end_lvl() should be compatible with Walker::end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array) in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\tourpackage\include\plugin\dropdown-menus.php on line 173
```

How can i fix this problem?
I am WAMP user.

Comment: check this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111557/strict-standards-error-bootstrap-navwalker

Comment: Now I get empty page.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning. You can correct it with standard declaration like Walker style by adding full functional defines and arrays.
Ex: end_lvl(); --> endlvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0);